# Why can't I loop through each of the table rows loaded dynamically in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

The table I am working with is loaded at runtime via ajax, I am trying to loop through all the rows in the table, using the code below:

```
alert("here"+jQuery('#contentItems table.tablesorter table tbody tr')); //I get here[Object object]
jQuery('#contentItems table.tablesorter table tbody tr').each(function(){
                alert("test");
           });
```

I get the first alert, but no alerts for `test`.

Oh and this code is running from the document's mouseup event.

Any suggetions?

Comment: What does `jQuery('#contentItems table.tablesorter table tbody tr').length` give you?  Also could you post example markup?

Comment: See if your selector is working: alert(jQuery('#contentItems table.tablesorter table tbody tr').length)

Comment: My first instinct is that the selector is wrong, but without further context I can't tell. One question, it looks like you have a table nested inside another one (the 'table.tablesorter table' part) according to your selector. Is this the case or is it a typo? (just wondering cause I don't usually see that)

Comment: Is it possible that you're calling this BEFORE your AJAX request is complete?

Comment: Did you mean "jQuery('#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr')".  Or do you have a table nested in a table (with the class tablesorter)?

Comment: oops...this is what you get for trying to code at 2 AM in the morning. THANKS EVERYONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you probably have an extra table tag in your selectors.

This:

```
'#contentItems table.tablesorter table tbody tr'
```

Might need to be:

```
'#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr'
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
jQuery.each(jQuery('#contentItems table.tablesorter table tbody tr'), function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
jQuery('#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr').each(function(){
                alert("test");
           });
```

I would also add one more thing if you dont have multiple tables with the same class i.e tablesorter you can just do

```
jQuery('table.tablesorter tbody tr').each(function(){
                alert("test");
           });
```

the performance gain by first filtering on id and then on the class will be negligible and the time for jquery to process these multi-level selector might just end up equaling the time of filtering on the id